# Update list with a item modification with linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Suppose i have a list

```
List<ABCClass> lstABC; // it has some data
```

now  need to modify a item from list like

```
var item = lstABC.Where(a=>a.index == 1).FirstOrDefault();
if(item != null)
    item.Number = 5;
```

now what is the most efficient way to assign this item in lstABC again because i need updated lstABC without creating new list and assign to it.

Comment: there is no need - it's already referenced

Comment: See also: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: If you wanted to swap out the item for a whole new item, then you'd have to jump through some hoops. But, in your case, you are simply changing a property of an item that the list references (and will continue to reference after your change).

Answer (score 0):

As JohnB pointed out in the comments, if `ABCClass` really is a `class` (and not a `struct`), then `item` refers to the object in the list, and any change to it will be visible next time you run through the list.

However, if `ABCClass` really is a `struct`, then `item` is just a copy of the object in the list, and changes to it will not be reflected in the list.

if that case (which is unlikely), you'd need to do something list this:

```
List<int> lstABC; // it has some data
var idx = lstABC.FindIndex(a => a.index == 1);
if (idx != -1)
    lstABC[idx].Number = 5;
```